# How to copy sent message to a folder in a different account?

Tags: vba, outlook

I’m trying to find an ItemSend solution to copy the outgoing email to the clipboard, to drop it (ctrl-v) in a folder in a different account?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `MailItem.SaveSentMessageFolder` property to point to a different folder (`MAPIFolder`).

In case of multiple stores (`SaveSentMessageFolder` must point to a folder in the same store), you can use `Items.ItemAdd` event on the Sent Items folder and move the item explicitly to a different folder using `MailItem.Move`.

Comment: @Dimitry yes, I tried already but it works if you have only one email account. If you have more than one account, it doesn’t matter what folder you choose, it saves the email always in your account. The Set objFolder = objNS.PickFolder shows you all accounts with all subfolders. But it ignores all except your own account

Comment: SaveSentMessageFolder must point to a folder in the same store. It does not work across stores. You can also use `Items.ItemAdd` on the Sent Items folder and move the item explicitly to a different folder using `MailItem.Move`.

Comment: @Dimitry. The code below is roughly what I want to do. But unfortunately it doesn't work.

Comment: Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim objDestFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim objItem As Outlook.MailItem
    
    Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    'Pick the destination folders
    Set objDestFolder = objNS.PickFolder
  
    If Not (objDestFolder Is Nothing) Then
        Set objItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        
        objItem.Move objDestFolder
        
    End If

    Set objDestFolder = Nothing
    Set objNS = Nothing
    
End Sub

Comment: Doe not work in what sense? Why are you moving the item selected in the active explorer?

Comment: @Dimitry. The idea is that when a mail is sent, the user can select the folder in the pickfolder object in which he stores the sent mail. When I run the attached code, I get an error. If I step it and wait from line to line of code, the task will be performed correctly.
Something with Set objItem = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item (1) must be wrong.

Comment: Of course it is wrong - why are you moving some other item that happens to be selected in the Explorer?